# How to change services storage location in wso2 governancy registry

Tags: wso2, wso2-governance-registry

i have gone through wso2 doc:
https://docs.wso2.com/display/Governance460/Changing+Storage+Location+of+Services

when i change the location of services in regisrty.xml file.

```
<staticConfiguration>
    <versioningProperties>true</versioningProperties>
    <versioningComments>true</versioningComments>
    <versioningTags>true</versioningTags>
    <versioningRatings>true</versioningRatings>
    <!-- Location you want to add service and default location will be /services/ -->
    <servicePath>/trunk/services/mylocation</servicePath>
</staticConfiguration>
```

when ever tried to register a service throwing following exception:

ERROR {org.wso2.carbon.governance.api.common.GovernanceArtifactManager} -  Failed to add artifact: artifact id: 153b122e-5b4f-4e8e-bbe0-e7934da571d0, path: /trunk/services/mylocation/sample/com/myservice. Resource does not exist at path /_system/governance/trunk/services/sample/com
org.wso2.carbon.registry.core.exceptions.ResourceNotFoundException: Resource does not exist at path /_system/governance/trunk/services/sample/com

how to resolve the error

Thanks in advance...

Comment: Hope below answer help you to solve the issue? let us know if you have any questions.

Answer (score 0):

Try it in rxt level, Go to Home  > Extensions    > Configure     > Artifact Types    > Artifact Source(select the Artifact type) and change the storage path by changing the below line,

```
<storagePath>/trunk/services/@{namespace}/@{overview_version}/@{name}</storagePath>
```